# Socketio - Changing data sent on connection

Tags: javascript, security, socket.io

I'm trying to send `userid` from client side to server via `socket io query string` on the fly:

```
var socketio = io.connect(8080, {query : 'userid=100'});
```

And on server side, I use this id for authentication.
However, I'm a little worried about this. I thought that some malicious users may change `userid` and send to server their own id.

Am I thinking right? What should I do in this case?

Comment: Yes, anything in the browser can be manipulated. What you should probably do is reorganize your authentication method - why are you passing an ID **from** the frontend? Like where does it come from? I usually store the user ID in the server session. At the same time, the user *could* change their session ID in the cookie to another they know about (highly unlikely they'll know another one or guess correctly, but still possible).

Comment: Actually I use both `socketio` and `PHP` in my web app. And the `user session` is stored on PHP side. ~~

Comment: Okay, so what's the `userid` for? Like I said, the user can change anything they want in their browser (limited to what the browser provides direct access to). So they technically could change variables and things like what you have. You kinda have to trust them and let them do what they want (or let your web app run like normal) and secure it on the server. For example, if that user shouldn't be allowed to query by that `userid`, then throw an error on the backend.

Comment: I use this id for editing user data. Do you mean that I need to stop doing this way? I know that JS can be changed on client side. However, in order to change this data, the attacker need to reconnect `socketio`. I just don't know how an attacker can do it, because the connection is only established on load.

Comment: What's stopping the user from opening up Dev Tools, closing the connection, and opening a new one? You need to stop worrying about this on the frontend, because it's unavoidable. Secure your server and it will be fine

Comment: You've just revealed my mind about security. Thank you so much Ian.

Comment: No problem. I have the same concerns every day, but I have to reassure myself there's only so much I can do. As long as I secure the server, things will be fine. We can always obfuscate the code, try to hide it in places, things like that, but it will always be exposed. Browsers are improving and providing even more options for users to do almost anything to the page/DOM, and there's nothing we can really do (but there's nothing more we should do on the frontend).